# Decrease in accuracy of TensorRt model (pytorch->onnx->TensorRT) on jetson nano

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am inferencing TensorRt model on jetson nano. It is converted from pytorch through onnx.
At the time of inference, the accuracy of TensorRt model has decreased drastically.
It is an object detection type model.

link for code:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/467

Comment: Please add more information. How did you infer the accuracy has decreased? Also do add your code.

Comment: I have checked its score and compare it with the original model.

Comment: If you could share your code, we would know better what can be the issue.

Comment: I have shared a link for the code.

Comment: hi @IbrahimYousuf 
if more explanation is required than tell me I will share that as well.

Comment: You are using the same postprocessing in TensorRT and PyTorch?

Comment: yes, I have used same postprocessing.

Comment: I don't see it in the code? Please also share the output values from TensorRT and PyTorch.

Comment: Thanks I have figure out the problem. I don't why but type of input effect the accuracy of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the problem. I don't know why but type of input effect the accuracy of model.

I have replace

img_raw = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

by

img_raw = imageio.imread(image_path)

I will update the answer if I get to know the reason behind it.

Comment: What type did you change it to? And please specify the code line.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf
I have replace
img_raw = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
by 
img_raw = imageio.imread(image_path)